# PhpStorm not showing project files in project view

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

After I had installed PhpStorm and created a project from an existing source files, The project pane is not showing any file from the directory. 
So how can we solve the problem?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

After investigation on the issue, I got the solution as follow:

1. Remove .idea directory from your root project directory
2. Invalidate and restart your IDE , FILE -> Invalidate  cache /Restart -> then click on Invalidate cache and restart
3. You are done :)

Here is the source

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207066915-Project-view-not-showing-directories

Comment: if this solution wont working instead of #2 close the project then open it again after #1

Comment: note that you might loose some customized settings when you delete .idea.

Comment: This did not work for me.  On PhpStorm version 2021.1.1

Comment: This will delete a lot of potentially important stuff like unit test settings.

Comment: Scroll a little below and check out the solution which works without any invalidation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65644645/1101589

Answer (score 95):

In case both above solutions do not work, try this following approach:

1. `cd` to your projects `.idea` Folder
2. Check if there is a file called `project_name.iml`. If this is not the case create it and paste the following content to it

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <module type="WEB_MODULE" version="4">
     <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
       <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$"></content>
     </component>
   </module>
   ```
3. Then check if there is a file called `modules.xml`. If this is not the case create it and paste the following content to it (which targets to your previously created `project_name.iml`)

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project version="4">
     <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
       <modules>
         <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/project_name.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/project_name.iml" />
       </modules>
     </component>
   </project>
   ```
4. Restart PhpStorm

Comment: The accepted solution didn't work for me. This one yes, just after step 3. No need to restart. But I did it completely. Thanks bro

Comment: Thank you for this!!    I had no interest in deleting my `.idea` folder and losing all my settings after a colleague unintentionally committed his .idea folder and overwrote stuff in mine when I checked it out. This got things working for me again where invalidating the cache and other solutions did not.

Comment: This helped restore my "Always Select Opened File" option in the Project Files pane.  Apparently "Always Select Opened File" only works on project files, and my corrupted .idea file saw all my project files as non-project.

Comment: Re-linking the modules.xml file with my newly named project fixed the problem immediately. A note for anyone who might have issues, project_name.iml is a placeholder. So if your project is named MyAwesomeProject, look for MyAwesomeProject.iml and then re-link in modules.xml.

Answer (score 51):

I was able to resolve this in PhpStorm 2021.2.4 with the following steps:

- Exit PhpStorm
- Remove the existing .idea folder (like so `rm -rf .idea`)
- Restart PhpStorm
- click **File** > **Open** to select your project directory

Everything should be fine now.

Comment: Just had this happen today. Exit PhpStorm and restart. Your missing project view should now show up. If not, follow the steps above.

Comment: Thanks for this, step 1 is very important.

Comment: this worked for me using Webstorm. The trick seems like deleting that .idea file while the IDE is closed /shrug

Comment: @ConnerSmith yea it would seem so.

Comment: This should be the answer for all jetbrains IDE's!

Does anyone actually know what is causing this glitch? I remember this happening for the whole 6 years I'm using jetbrains products

Comment: Thanks, This helped me! :)   Note:- You will lose some of the customized settings when you remove the existing .idea directory.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer did not work me. What worked for me was

> File > Repair IDE...

And you'll be prompted in the lower right side corner with some alerts that have suggestions. Click on those until its fixed.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Go to the menu File -> Settings -> Directories and then delete the current directory and add a new directory with the root of your project that worked for me.

Ingresas al menú File -> Settings -> Directories  y luego eliminas el directorio actual y agregar un nuevo directorio con la raíz de tu proyecto eso funciono para mi.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ytxm.png)

Comment: This is what worked for me. Initially the Directories window was blank. After following @ Mustafa Yousef 's steps above (which didn't in themselves fix it), and re-starting PhpStorm, then I was able to do this. Only 5 hours lost to this ... !

Comment: This did the trick for me. The directory list was empty. Needed to select the project folder as "Content root".

Comment: Thank you, it helped even without restarting or invalidation. It happened for me the second time and your answer helped!

Answer (score 2):

For my version of Phpstorm the solution was to go to:

1. File > Close Project
2. Click on the gear icon of the project in question > Remove from Recent
   Projects
3. Click New Project > Select the folder path > Click on Create button > Click the button Create from Existing Sources.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above solution and was not successful.  The following, however did work.

1. Close all projects.
2. On the list of project, select yours, right click, and chose "Remove from Recent Projects".
3. Click "New Project" and choose your project's directory and click "Create"
4. In the "Directory Is Not Empty" dialog, click "Create from Existing Source".

When I opened the "new" project, everything was there including the Local History—thank the Gods!

Ref: PhpStorm version 2021.1.1 on Mac Catalina.

Comment: Yes works. But beware: your deployment settings and other stuff can be lost.

Answer (score 1):

I had selected this option by mistake

[image]

Comment: For real, thank you for posting this.

Answer (score -3):

I fixed this by resetting my IDE default settings

**File -> Manage IDE settings -> Restore default settings**

*Note that this will remove all your plugins and configurations*